# How to Give few lines of input from python interpreter, instead of a file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, interpreter

I am learning python. I want my program to take input (name and age) and add to list as tuple, sort the input by age and print out. I don't know the size of the input.

**My code:**

```
list = []
while(True):
    try:
        name,age = input().split()
        list.append((age,name))
    except StopIteration:
        break
list.sort()
print(list)
```

**input:**

```
DUCHESS 26
MARIE 8
BERLIOZ 8
TOULOUSE 7
THOMAS 28
```

I have two questions:

1) How to run this `.py` file in my interpreter ? It gives this error message when I type all the input and press enter `ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack`

2) Even when I run this program on ideone, it is giving run time error message. What am I doing wrong?

And also, what is the best approach for this problem? Using a `dictionary`?

Answer (score 0):

If somebody enters an empty string, than `''.split()` returns `[]`, hence you cannot `a,b = []`. And it throws `ValueError` instead of `StopIteration`.

Here is a fixed version:

```
list = []
while True:
    try:
        name,age = input().split()
        list.append((age,name))
    except Exception:
        break
list.sort()
print(list)
```

Output:

```
sait@Saits-MacBook-Pro:~/Desktop$ python3 a.py
DUCHESS 26
MARIE 8
BERLIOZ 8
TOULOUSE 7
THOMAS 28

[('26', 'DUCHESS'), ('28', 'THOMAS'), ('7', 'TOULOUSE'), ('8', 'BERLIOZ'), ('8', 'MARIE')]
```

Comment: Thanks,  but I am using Python  3, and yes, the input given is correct. I want to know how to give input from interpreter, instead of a file.

Comment: Then can you remove the Python-2.7 tag from your post, please?

Comment: @Charan I added the output on the command-line too, if it helps.